# Spark parquet assign index within group

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know the most efficient way to generate column `index`
to unique identify a record **within each group of label:**

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| label | value | index |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | v1    | 0     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | v2    | 1     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | v3    | 2     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | v4    | 3     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| b     | v5    | 0     |
+-------+-------+-------+
| b     | v6    | 1     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

My actual data is very large and each group of label has the same number of records. Column index will be used for Pivot.
I could do the usual sort + for-loop incremental + check if cur<>pre then reset index, etc but a faster and more efficient way is always welcome.

EDIT: got my answer from the suggested question:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn("index", 
                   F.row_number().over(
                       Window.partitionBy("label").orderBy("value"))
                  )
```

Thank you for all your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Window` functions to create a rank based column while partitioning on the `label` column. However, this requires an ordering - in this case on `value`:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

window = Window.partitionBy(df['label']).orderBy(df['value'])
df.withColumn('index', row_number().over(window))
```

This will give a new column `index` with values starting from 1 (to start from 0, simply add `-1` to the expression above). The values will be given as ordered by the `value` column.

Comment: rank() will have issue when `value`s are the same, better use `row_number()`.

Comment: @jxc That is a good point. I updated the answer.